# CSS Wildcard selector for an element on all WooCommerce product categories only

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I am working on a WordPress website with WooCommerce. I want to style class .content-area but only on ***product category*** pages. If I was to pick a single category (for example category with tag ID 15), my CSS code would look like this:

```
.term-15 .content-area {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

This works, but it only styles the .content-area element on that particular product category #15. What I'm after is to style that element on **all product categories - BUT NOT on the rest of the website**. I was trying to research the wildcard selector, but can't figure it out:

```
[class^='term-'] .content-area {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this by using a wildcard; or any other way?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. A simple solution:

```
.tax-product_cat .content-area {
    margin-top:0;
}
```